# DotVVM - DateTime json conversion not working

Tags: datetime, dotvvm

I'm new to DotVVM and just playing with it for the moment.

My model has a DateTime property
When i edit this in a form with

```
  <dot:TextBox   Text="{value: Datum}"  size="20" />
```

Full datetime is shown like "2018-02-08T13:02:42.0000000"
Editing the string is possible, and sending the object back to the viewmodel works fine.

When i add a Formatstring like "yyyy-MM-dd"  the property is NULL in the json sent to the app.

How can i fix this?
Is it possible to include my own JsonConverter for DateTime conversion?  (In this example i only need the date property)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use dates in TextBox, you need to add `ValueType="DateTime"` (and to use specific format, you can add `FormatString="d"` for example).

Comment: Thank you.  Nice project btw.